# How could I...? vs How could I have...?

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

To my knowledge, both ***How could I...?*** and ***How could I have...?*** can be used to express disbelief at something you did in the past or you have just done. What could be the difference, if there is any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***could*** is for past ability. (We're not using it as a conditional clause.)

> *How could I do this?* (I did it and I'm asking myself this.)

***could have*** is for past possibility.

> *How could I have done this?* (There was a way to do this, but I didn't, so I'm asking myself this.)

Comment: But couldn't we say, "How could I have done something so stupid?" when we really did/have done some insensible act?

Comment: If you did it, you use *How could I do something so stupid?*